# How do I prevent unfilled UITextFields from showing up on a randomized count? Xcode

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, nsarray, arc4random

I am working on an app in which there are five **UITextFields in one view controller**, the user can fill the text fields they want and when they press a **UIButton** they'll get a **randomized answer on a second view controller** via a UILabel.

I got it to work so far, but let's say the user *only fills the first two UITextFields* and the random answer they get is from a *blank, unfilled UITextField*.

My question is: how do I make work so that the **unfilled UITextFields** are not part of the random count?  Is this possible?

Here's the code:

**FifthViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.choice1.delegate = self;
self.choice2.delegate = self;
self.choice3.delegate = self;
self.choice4.delegate = self;
self.choice5.delegate = self;
}


- (IBAction)choicebutton:(id)sender {

SixthViewController *SVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SixthViewController"];

SVC.stringFromChoice1 = self.choice1.text;
SVC.stringFromChoice2 = self.choice2.text;
SVC.stringFromChoice3 = self.choice3.text;
SVC.stringFromChoice4 = self.choice4.text;
SVC.stringFromChoice5 = self.choice5.text;


[self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

**SixthViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.choiceAnswers = @[self.stringFromChoice1,
                       self.stringFromChoice2,
                       self.stringFromChoice3,
                       self.stringFromChoice4,
                       self.stringFromChoice5];




int index = arc4random() % [self.choiceAnswers count];
self.choiceanswer.text = self.choiceAnswers[index];


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SixthViewController

You can check and see if a string is empty before adding it to self.choiceAnswers:

```
if(![self.stringFromChoice1 isEqualToString@""]);
{
    [self.choiceAnswers addObject:self.stringFromChoice1];
}
```

Make sure that you are using an NSMutable array for self.choiceAnswers.